# How can I calculate median between my changepoint locations?

Tags: r, median, trendline

I have a data frame and applied the **changepoint.np** package to it. Now I want to calculate the median or display a trendline between these changepoint locations (red lines) to it.

[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

My dataframe df1

```
 date           amount
2012-07-01    20.0000000
2012-08-01    11.1111111
2012-09-01    0.0000000
2012-10-01    0.0000000
2012-11-01    4.7619048
2012-12-01    4.7619048
2013-01-01    7.8947368
2013-02-01    0.0000000
2013-03-01    0.0000000
2013-04-01    1.8181818
2013-05-01    0.0000000
2013-06-01    0.0000000
2013-07-01    0.0000000
2013-08-01    0.0000000
2013-09-01    1.7543860
2013-10-01    0.6410256
2013-11-01    3.0534351
2013-12-01    2.6143791
2014-01-01    7.6023392
2014-02-01    2.7777778
2014-03-01    5.2884615
2014-04-01    2.7237354
2014-05-01    2.3255814
2014-06-01    2.6627219
2014-07-01    2.0710059
2014-08-01    2.7522936
2014-09-01    4.6413502
2014-10-01    4.4077135
2014-11-01    3.4759358
2014-12-01    4.3333333
2015-01-01    8.0128205
2015-02-01    9.3632959
2015-03-01    4.3771044
2015-04-01    4.0650407
2015-05-01    3.7500000
2015-06-01    4.6189376
2015-07-01    3.6764706
2015-08-01    2.4561404
2015-09-01    2.9090909
2015-10-01    2.1084337
```

And my code for the changepoint:

```
library(changepoint.np) 

out <- cpt.np(df1$amount, method = 'PELT')
plot(out)
```

Comment: please add the dataset, and code as well

Answer (score 0):

`median(df1$amount)` for the median, for the trendline you would first have to tell us the actual values. Lines can be added to a plot with the `lines()` function, that is coordinates for first and last point.